# Actionscript- How do I set a click handler on a tab in TabNavigator?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I want the TextArea under my second tab to update when the tab is clicked.  However, it's only updating when I click on the TextArea or the container for that text area.

Flex:

```
 <mx:Box paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0" width="100%" height="100%"
 <mx:VBox id="vbxHTMLBody" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalAlign="center">
   <mx:TabNavigator id = "tabNav" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" height="100%" creationPolicy="all">
     <mx:VBox label="Tab1" width="100%" height="100%">
          <mx:TextArea id="textArea1" paddingTop="25" paddingLeft="25" paddingRight="25" verticalScrollPolicy="on" focusThickness="0" borderThickness="0" borderStyle="none" editable="true" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14" width="100%" height="100%"/>
     </mx:VBox>
     <mx:VBox label="Tab2" width="100%" height="100%" click="updateTextArea2()">    
          <mx:TextArea id="textArea2" paddingTop="25" paddingLeft="25" paddingRight="25" verticalScrollPolicy="on" focusThickness="0" borderThickness="0" borderStyle="none" editable="true" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14" width="100%" height="100%"/>
     </mx:VBox>
   </mx:TabNavigator>
 </mx:VBox>
 </mx:Box>
```

ActionScript:

```
private function updateTextArea2(): void {
    textArea2.htmlText = textArea1.text;
    tabNav.validateNow();
    textArea2.validateNow();
}
```

*I've also tried setting the click listener to the outer containers and that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

I used change="updateTextArea2()" to listen for any changes made to the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Call `updateTextArea2()`on change of the `TabNavigator`:

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabNav" change=updateTextArea2()">
```

instead from `VBox` change.